# Python Turtle Game--Tilt function

Tags: python, python-turtle

So I'm trying to make a game similar to Stick Hero, where the goal is to estimate the correct length in order to pass to the next building. Right now I have it so the length of the path grows as the space bar is pressed and then falls down to see if the player made the correct length. My dilemma is that every time the length of the path is changed, it must be moved so it falls down correctly (touches the edge of the first building). Right now the drop_path() function determines how many times the length was changed then positions the path correctly

```
def drop_path():
    path_pos = -360
    path.tilt(90)
    if grow_count == 1:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 24
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 2:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 27
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 3:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 29
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 4:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 32
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 5:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 34
        path.setx(path_pos)
```

etc. I realize this is probably not the best way to do this which is what I need help with

- BTW this whole problem could be avoided if the path could be pivoted at the bottom
  [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBjso.png)

Help is much appreciated please ask If you need clarification

```
#-----import statements-----
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand

#-----game configuration----
wn  = trtl.Screen()
wn.setup(1000,500)
wn.bgpic("city_background.png")
painter = trtl.Turtle()
game_over = False
wn.addshape('hero_image.gif')

path_len = 2
#-----initialize turtle-----
building = trtl.Turtle()
building.penup()
building.color("mediumslateblue")
building.pencolor("mediumslateblue")
building.goto(-400,-150)
building.shape("square")
building.shapesize(11,4)

hero = trtl.Turtle()
hero.shape("circle")
hero.penup()
hero.goto(-400,-30)
path = trtl.Turtle()
path.setheading(90)

grow_count = 0
forward_len = 22

#-----game functions--------
def make_structure():
    new_building = trtl.Turtle()
    new_building = building.clone()
    new_building.forward(200)
    width = rand.randint(1,8)
    new_building.shapesize(11, width)

def make_path():
    path.shape("square")
    path.penup()
    path.goto(-360,-20)
    path.shapesize(.25,2)

def grow_path():
    global path_len, grow_count,forward_len
    grow_count += 1
    forward_len += 2.5
    path_len += .25
    path.forward(2.5)
    path.shapesize(.25, path_len)
    print(grow_count) 
   
def drop_path():
    path_pos = -360
    path.tilt(90)
    if grow_count == 1:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 24
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 2:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 27
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 3:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 29
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 4:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 32
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 5:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 34
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 6:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 37
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 7:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 39
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 8:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 41
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 9:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 43
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 10:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 46
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 11:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 48
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 12:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 51
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 13:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 53
        path.setx(path_pos)
    elif grow_count == 14:
        path.backward(forward_len)
        path_pos += 56
        path.setx(path_pos)
    
#-----events----------------

make_path()
make_structure()
wn.onkeypress(grow_path, "space")
wn.onkeypress(drop_path, "g")
wn.update()
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `shapesize()` to adjust the path, we can also use `shapesize()`, with no arguments, to interrogate the current shape of the path.  With that information, we can calculate where to place the tilted path:

```
#-----import statements-----
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

#-----game functions--------
def make_structure():
    new_building = building.clone()
    new_building.forward(200)
    width = randint(1, 8)
    new_building.shapesize(11, width)

def make_path():
    path = Turtle()
    path.shape('square')
    path.penup()
    path.goto(-362.5, -20)
    path.setheading(90)
    path.shapesize(.25, 2)

    return path

path_len = 2

def grow_path():
    global path_len

    path_len += 0.25
    path.forward(2.5)
    path.shapesize(0.25, path_len)

    screen.update()

def drop_path():
    path.tilt(90)

    stretch_wid, stretch_len, _ = path.shapesize()

    path.backward(stretch_len * 10 + stretch_wid * 10)
    path.setx(path.xcor() + stretch_len * 10)

    screen.update()

#-----game configuration----

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1000, 500)
screen.tracer(False)

#-----initialize turtle-----
building = Turtle()
building.shape('square')
building.shapesize(11, 4)
building.color('mediumslateblue')
building.penup()
building.goto(-400, -150)

path = make_path()

make_structure()

#-----events----------------

screen.onkeypress(grow_path, 'space')
screen.onkeypress(drop_path, 'g')
screen.listen()
screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```

I've simplified your example code, removing anything that doesn't affect the issue we're trying to resolve.  I've also turned on `tracer()`, and expanded the number of `update()` calls, to make the movement appear smoother.